# encodeURIComponent equivalent object-c

Tags: javascript, objective-c

I'm having trouble googling this.

Does Objective-C have an equivalent method for encoding URI Component?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

This seems to be a very common use case but I can't find any documentation about it in Objective-C.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

[`-[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BCIBFDCB) is the simplest way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

off course, you can choose this methods, I hope that will be helpful.

```
//encode URL string

+(NSString *)URLEncodedString:(NSString *)str
{

    NSString *encodedString = (NSString *)
    CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                              (CFStringRef)str,
                                                              NULL,
                                                              (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                              kCFStringEncodingUTF8));

    return encodedString;
}

}

//decode URL string

+(NSString *)URLDecodedString:(NSString *)str
{

  NSString *decodedString=(__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)str, CFSTR(""), CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding));

    return decodedString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` is deprecated. Here's the iOS 7+ equivalent of `encodeURIComponent`:

```
[str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]]
```

Comment: This code is not equivalent to Javascript's `encodeURIComponent()` since `NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` also allows characters like `&` or `?`. This is more evident when trying to pass an URL as a query parameter to another URL. For instance, check the output of the code on this URL (which would be taken as a query param value itself): `http://www.a.com/path?a=b&c=d`. Check my answer for a solution that encodes it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Using `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` or `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is not ideal since those are **deprecated** methods.

Dave's answer is on the right track but is not explicit enough.

We want to call `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` but we need to choose a character set. Despite what our intuiton might say, `NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` is actually not a good choice. It refers to the whole query part of the URL, not just to values of query parameters so it allows characters like `?` or `&` as well, which are not valid here. What you want is to manually build the allowed characters set according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent#description) and use that. The allowed chars for `encodeURIComponent()` are:

```
A–Z a–z 0–9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )
```

That gives us this solution:

```
// Note: Using NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet is inappropriate for this purpose.
// It contains the allowed chars for the whole Query part of the URL (including '?' or '&'),
// not just for the values of query parameters (where chars are more restricted).

+ (NSString *)encodeURIComponent:(NSString *)uriComponent {
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent
    NSString *allowedChars = @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                              "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                              "0123456789"
                              "-_.!~*'()";

    NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:allowedChars];
    return [uriComponent stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:charSet];
}

+ (NSString *)decodeURIComponent:(NSString *)uriComponent {
    return [uriComponent stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
}
```